# Post-Civil War Not Able to Decorate Hjerim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have completely finished the civil war quest line for the imperials. I finished the blood on the ice quest line after the civil war quest line, once everything was cleaned up and Lonely-Gale was the steward. I bought the house from him, visited the house, and came back but there is no dialogue to decorate the house in any way. Has anyone else had this problem? If so, do you know how to fix it?